# Why my noise model acts different on my VQE circuit compared to a simple circuit

Tags: qiskit, noise

I have created a noise model which uses depolarizing error and I add it using the add to all qubits quantum error command. I also use readout error and add that using the add to all qubits readoute error command.

When I've tested this noisemodel on a simple circuit I can successfully vary the amount of noise the circuit receives, however when I try to add it in to my VQE code which is the code from the QisKit textbook, when I increase the parameters there isn't a noticeable change.

I was thinking this is because the VQE algorithm is already quite good at handling noise, however when I am increasing these parameters by a power of 10 there should be some sort of change.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code for my simple example:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute
from qiskit import IBMQ, Aer
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
from qiskit_aer.noise import NoiseModel

# Build noise model from backend properties
provider = IBMQ.load_account()
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_quito')
noise_model = NoiseModel.from_backend(backend)

# Get coupling map from backend
coupling_map = backend.configuration().coupling_map

# Get basis gates from noise model
basis_gates = noise_model.basis_gates

# Make a circuit
circ = QuantumCircuit(3, 3)
circ.h(0)
circ.cx(0, 1)
circ.cx(1, 2)
circ.measure([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2])

# Perform a noise simulation
result = execute(circ, Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'),
                 coupling_map=coupling_map,
                 basis_gates=basis_gates,
                 noise_model=noise_model).result()
counts = result.get_counts(0)
plot_histogram(counts)
```

The reuslts from this are below
[image: The results from this example]

I then created by own noisemodel with the following

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute, Aer
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
import qiskit_aer.noise as noise
from qiskit.providers.aer.noise import QuantumError, ReadoutError

# Error probabilities
prob_1 = 0.02  # 1-qubit gate
prob_2 = 0.2  # 2-qubit gate

# Depolarizing quantum errors
error_1 = noise.depolarizing_error(prob_1, 1)
error_2 = noise.depolarizing_error(prob_2, 2)

# Readout quantum errors
p0given1 = 0.1
p1given0 = 0.05

ReadoutError = ReadoutError([[1 - p1given0, p1given0], [p0given1, 1 - p0given1]])

# Add errors to noise model
noise_model = noise.NoiseModel()
noise_model.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(error_1, ['u1', 'u2', 'u3'])
noise_model.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(error_2, ['cx'])
noise_model.add_all_qubit_readout_error(ReadoutError)
print(noise_model)
# Get basis gates from noise model
basis_gates = noise_model.basis_gates

# Make a circuit
circ = QuantumCircuit(3, 3)
circ.h(0)
circ.cx(0, 1)
circ.cx(1, 2)
circ.measure([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2])

# Perform a noise simulation
result = execute(circ, Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'),
                 basis_gates=basis_gates,
                 noise_model=noise_model).result()
counts = result.get_counts(0)
plot_histogram(counts)
```

And I get the following:

[image: Own noise model results]

I can then change my parameters: prob_1, prob_2, p0given1 and p1given0
Increasing these increases my noise, decreasing these decreases my noise. This is what I wanted to achieve of having controllable noise. Then when I take this code over to my VQE code I add them to a noise model through the following:

```
noise_model1 = noise.NoiseModel()
noise_model1.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(error_1, ['u1', 'u2', 'u3'])
noise_model1.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(error_2, ['cx'])
noise_model1.add_all_qubit_readout_error(readout_error)
sim_noise = AerSimulator(noise_model=noise_model1)
qi = QuantumInstance(sim_noise,
                    noise_model=noise_model1)
```

This then gives me the quantum instance which I can use in my VQE code. However all of my results are very similar even if I'm changing my probabilities massively. Even when I put the probabilities to almost no error it still acts as if I have set the probabilities to a very high error.

Below is my entire VQE code:
Note: I am aware that I could nest my parameters increasing in size into a loop instead of using if statements, I've just done it this way to help me visualize.

I also have 3 parameters p_reset,p_meas and p_gate1 which I used when testing a different type of "quantum_error" which also didn't help improving my results so these can be ignored. They aren't applied to the noisemodel.

I also have tried with 'qasm_simulator' and AerSimulator, both give the same result and don't really change with changes in these parameters.

```
from qiskit.algorithms import VQE
from qiskit.algorithms import NumPyMinimumEigensolver
from qiskit_nature.algorithms import (GroundStateEigensolver,
                                      NumPyMinimumEigensolverFactory)
from qiskit_nature.drivers import Molecule
from qiskit_nature.drivers.second_quantization import (
    ElectronicStructureMoleculeDriver, ElectronicStructureDriverType)
from qiskit_nature.transformers.second_quantization.electronic import FreezeCoreTransformer
from qiskit_nature.problems.second_quantization import ElectronicStructureProblem
from qiskit_nature.converters.second_quantization import QubitConverter
from qiskit_nature.mappers.second_quantization import ParityMapper

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from qiskit_nature.circuit.library import UCCSD, HartreeFock
from qiskit.circuit.library import EfficientSU2
from qiskit.algorithms.optimizers import COBYLA, SPSA, SLSQP
from qiskit.opflow import TwoQubitReduction
from qiskit import BasicAer, Aer
from qiskit.utils import QuantumInstance
from qiskit.utils.mitigation import CompleteMeasFitter
from qiskit.providers.aer.noise import NoiseModel
import numpy as np
from qiskit.providers.aer import AerSimulator

# Importing standard Qiskit libraries
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile, Aer, IBMQ
from qiskit.providers.aer import QasmSimulator

def get_qubit_op(dist):
    molecule = Molecule(
        geometry=[ ["H", [0.0, 0.0, 0.0] ],
                  ["H", [dist, 0.0, 0.0725] ]],
        multiplicity=1,charge=0)

    driver = ElectronicStructureMoleculeDriver(
        molecule=molecule,
        basis="sto3g",
        driver_type=ElectronicStructureDriverType.PYSCF)

    problem = ElectronicStructureProblem(driver)

    second_q_ops = problem.second_q_ops()  # Get 2nd Quant OP
    num_spin_orbitals = problem.num_spin_orbitals
    num_particles = problem.num_particles

    mapper = ParityMapper()  # Set Mapper

    hamiltonian = second_q_ops[0]  # Set Hamiltonian

    # Do two qubit reduction
    converter = QubitConverter(mapper,two_qubit_reduction=True)
    reducer = TwoQubitReduction(num_particles)
    qubit_op = converter.convert(hamiltonian)
    qubit_op = reducer.convert(qubit_op)
    return qubit_op, num_particles, num_spin_orbitals, problem, converter

from qiskit.providers.aer.noise import pauli_error
from qiskit import IBMQ
from qiskit.providers.aer.noise import NoiseModel, ReadoutError
from qiskit.providers.fake_provider import FakeMelbourne
backend = FakeMelbourne()
from qiskit.providers.aer.noise import depolarizing_error
nm_1 = NoiseModel.from_backend(backend)
import qiskit_aer.noise as noise
def custom_noise(idx): 
    # Error probabilities
    if idx == 0:
        prob_1 = 0.005  # 1-qubit gate
        prob_2 = 0.01   # 2-qubit gate
        p0_1 = 0.99
        p1_0 = 0.005
        p0 = 1 - p0_1
        p1 = 1 - p1_0
        p_reset = 0.015
        p_meas = 0.01
        p_gate1 = 0.0125
    elif idx == 1:
        prob_1 = 0.05  # 1-qubit gate
        prob_2 = 0.1   # 2-qubit gate
        p0_1 = 0.9
        p1_0 = 0.05
        p0 = 1 - p0_1
        p1 = 1 - p1_0
        p_reset = 0.15
        p_meas = 0.1
        p_gate1 = 0.125
    elif idx == 2:
        prob_1 = 0.1  # 1-qubit gate
        prob_2 = 0.2   # 2-qubit gate
        p0_1 = 0.8
        p1_0 = 0.1
        p0 = 1 - p0_1
        p1 = 1 - p1_0
        p_reset = 0.3
        p_meas = 0.2
        p_gate1 = 0.35
    elif idx == 3:
        prob_1 = 0.15  # 1-qubit gate
        prob_2 = 0.3   # 2-qubit gate
        p0_1 = 0.6
        p1_0 = 0.3
        p0 = 1 - p0_1
        p1 = 1 - p1_0
        p_reset = 0.45
        p_meas = 0.3
        p_gate1 = 0.475
    elif idx == 4:
        prob_1 = 0.2  # 1-qubit gate
        prob_2 = 0.4   # 2-qubit gate
        p0_1 = 0.5
        p1_0 = 0.4
        p0 = 1 - p0_1
        p1 = 1 - p1_0
        p_reset = 0.60
        p_meas = 0.4
        p_gate1 = 0.6
    print(prob_1,p0_1,p_reset)
    #adding quantum error objects
    '''
    error_reset = pauli_error([('X', p_reset), ('I', 1 - p_reset)])
    error_meas = pauli_error([('X',p_meas), ('I', 1 - p_meas)])
    error_gate1 = pauli_error([('X',p_gate1), ('I', 1 - p_gate1)])
    error_gate2 = error_gate1.tensor(error_gate1)
    '''
    
    # Depolarizing quantum errors
    error_1 = noise.depolarizing_error(prob_1, 1)
    error_2 = noise.depolarizing_error(prob_2, 2)
    
    #Readout errors
    readout_error = ReadoutError([[p0_1, p0], [p1_0, p1]])
    
    # Add errors to noise model
    noise_model1 = noise.NoiseModel()
   # noise_model.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(error_reset, "reset")
   # noise_model.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(error_meas, "measure")
   # noise_model.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(error_gate1, ["u1", "u2", "u3"])
   # noise_model.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(error_gate2, ["cx"])
   # noise_model.add_all_qubit_readout_error(readout_error)
    noise_model1.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(error_1, ['u1', 'u2', 'u3'])
    noise_model1.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(error_2, ['cx'])
    noise_model1.add_all_qubit_readout_error(readout_error)
    print(noise_model1)
    
    '''
    noise_model = NoiseModel()
    error = depolarizing_error(prob_1,1)
    noise_model.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(error, ['u1', 'u2', 'u3'])
    '''
    backend1 = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
    basis_gates = noise_model1.basis_gates
    sim_noise = AerSimulator(noise_model=noise_model1)
    qi = QuantumInstance(backend1,
                         noise_model=noise_model1,
                         basis_gates=basis_gates,
                         measurement_error_mitigation_cls=CompleteMeasFitter)
    return qi

def exact_solver(problem, converter):
    solver = NumPyMinimumEigensolverFactory()
    calc = GroundStateEigensolver(converter, solver)
    result = calc.solve(problem)
    return result

distances = np.arange(0.2, 2.5, 0.2)

for idx in range(0,5):
    exact_energies = []
    vqe_energies = []
    optimizer = SLSQP(maxiter=100)
    qi = custom_noise(idx)
    for dist in distances:
        (qubit_op, num_particles, num_spin_orbitals,
                                 problem, converter) = get_qubit_op(dist)
        result = exact_solver(problem,converter)
        exact_energies.append(result.total_energies[0])
        init_state = HartreeFock(num_spin_orbitals, num_particles, converter)
        var_form = EfficientSU2(qubit_op.num_qubits, entanglement="linear")
        vqe = VQE(var_form, optimizer=optimizer, quantum_instance=qi)
        vqe_calc = vqe.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(qubit_op)
        vqe_result = problem.interpret(vqe_calc).total_energies[0].real
        vqe_energies.append(vqe_result)
        print(f"Interatomic Distance: {np.round(dist, 2)}",
              f"VQE Result: {vqe_result:.5f}",
              f"Exact Energy: {exact_energies[-1]:.5f}")
    print("Energies for idx {} have been calculated".format(idx))
    plt.plot(distances, vqe_energies, label="VQE Energy index = {}".format(idx))
    
print("All energies have been calculated")
plt.plot(distances, exact_energies, label="Exact Energy")
plt.xlabel('Atomic distance (Angstrom)')
plt.ylabel('Energy')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Below are the results:
[image: Image of diff noises by similar]
This shows that increasing the noise doesn't have the same affect as which it has on my simple example above.

Comment: Hi! Please show code examples, otherwise it will be difficult to help you

Comment: @AlexeyUvarov Hello I have added some more detail for you.

Comment: Thanks! So far, everything you've added looks okay. However, please also add your VQE code which you say doesn't work as intended.

Comment: @AlexeyUvarov Thanks for the fast reply, I have added the code.

Comment: @AlexeyUvarov I have also added the plot for you too.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see where exactly the problem is. Perhaps, to simplify the situation, you can try fixing some parameters of the ansatz, some atomic distance, and then see if the noise affects the output. Then if you don't see anything there you might move to VQE.

Comment: @AlexeyUvarov Hey, I did something similar with just finding the minimum eigen state and increasing the noise with each iteration, this worked as it should with the result increasing every time the noise is increased. This means something is wrong with the VQE code which I don't know. However this is fine as I can finish my project without this piece of code now. Thanks for the help.